# Windows throws error after executing file

Tags: powershell

I am Trying to download a .exe which works but I get the "This App can't be run on your PC" error when I try to run it. This is my code (got it from [Powershell download and run exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47110728/14742651)):

```
$Download_Folder ="D:/Software/"

$application = "Crystaldiskinfo.exe"

#New-Item -ItemType File (Join-Path $Download_Folder $application)

$url = "https://sourceforge.net/projects/crystaldiskinfo/files/latest/download"
$outpath = "$Download_Folder/$application"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outpath

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $outpath)
```

Update: I got it to work with this code:

```
Start-Process "https://sourceforge.net/projects/crystaldiskinfo/files/latest/download"
Add-Type  @"
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Text;
public class APIFuncs
   {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd,StringBuilder
lpString, int cch);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
   public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
       public static extern Int32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd,out
Int32 lpdwProcessId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
       public static extern Int32 GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
    }
"@
 
sleep 3
$w = [apifuncs]::GetForegroundWindow()
$len = [apifuncs]::GetWindowTextLength($w)
$sb = New-Object text.stringbuilder -ArgumentList ($len + 1)
$rtnlen = [apifuncs]::GetWindowText($w,$sb,$sb.Capacity)
$application_name = $($sb.tostring())

Start-Sleep -s 10

#Sends keys to current application
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($application_name)
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~') # ~ is Enter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa202943(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#example)
```

Comment: I'll bet the size of that executable is about 115KB. The website says something like 5.8MB so, maybe, you should try to open this _**exe**_ file, in notepad, and find out it contains some HTML code  ....

Comment: Yes I had that too. I somehow managed to get the right size now but when I try to open it in Notepad it spits out a whole lot of jungle :/

Comment: OK, then you probably succeeded in downloading it correctly!

Comment: I updated it with a script that works. Now it works fine.

Comment: With the other script it still gets me that error :/

Comment: But you also might need to check the info under `ⓘ` (from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/crystaldiskinfo/files/9.2.1/?info ), to **KNOW** it really downloaded correctly.  (see: [Calculating SHA1 hash algorithm in PowerShell V2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232146/calculating-sha1-hash-algorithm-in-powershell-v2-0) or [How to get an MD5 checksum in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521061/how-to-get-an-md5-checksum-in-powershell)

Comment: Yeah got it, the SHA1 gave something different, so that means I downloaded something else with it the .exe rught?

Answer (score -1):

Script is derived from this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70010344/14742651

**!!! Script downloads some junk for this example which renders the .exe unusable. The Download link for the other software in the original post works fine with this script. !!!**

```
Add-Type  @"
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Text;
public class APIFuncs
   {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd,StringBuilder
lpString, int cch);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
   public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
       public static extern Int32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd,out
Int32 lpdwProcessId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
       public static extern Int32 GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
    }
"@
 
sleep 3
$w = [apifuncs]::GetForegroundWindow()
$len = [apifuncs]::GetWindowTextLength($w)
$sb = New-Object text.stringbuilder -ArgumentList ($len + 1)
$rtnlen = [apifuncs]::GetWindowText($w,$sb,$sb.Capacity)
$application_name = $($sb.tostring())

Start-Sleep -s 10

#Sends keys to current application
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($application_name)
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~') # ~ is Enter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa202943(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#example)
```

Comment: It is unclear how this answer will download `"Crystaldiskinfo.exe"`, like the question seems to ask.

Comment: It doesn’t, that’s why I marked it bold

Comment: Ok, so this _answer_ is not an **answer** (see: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and  [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))